# How to get Omega(n)

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

I have the formula a(n) = n * a(n-1) +1 ; a(0) = 0

How can i get the Omega, Theta or O Notation from this without the Master Theorem or did anyone have a good site to understand the explanation

Comment: what have you tried? Maybe you can start by writing down the definitions for Omega, Theta and big O - then you might want to write down a few values in this series to get a feeling for it's growth and behavior - now do you have a guess? - Come back when you did and still have issues with proofing your guess ;)

Comment: i wrote down all a(n) for n = 0...10 and i take this formula out, now i should write the Omega(n) but i don´t know how and i havn´t found a good explanation how i can do this

Comment: do you have a guess what your *Omega* (or better but what function `g(n` for your `a(n) = Omega(g(n))` could be?

Comment: my guess is that the Omega(n) is Omega(n!), because the algorithm is for permutation and the minimum is the normal quantitiy for a permutation of n thus n!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Master theorem doesn't even apply, so not being able to use it isn't much of a restriction.

An approach which works here is to guess upper and lower bounds, and then prove these guesses by induction if the guesses are good.

```
a(0) = 0
a(1) = 1
a(2) = 3
a(3) = 10
a(4) = 41
```

A reasonable guess for a lower bound is that a(n) >= n! for n>1. This is true for n=1. Suppose it is true for n=k-1.

```
a(k) = ka(k-1)+1 
     >= k (k-1)! + 1 
     >= k!.
```

So, if it is true for n=k-1, then it is true for n=k, so a(n) >= n! for all positive integers n, and a(n) = Omega(n!).

A reasonable guess for an upper bound is at a(n) <= 2(n!). This is true for the first few values, but it turns out to be a little awkward to prove using induction. Sometimes with inductive proofs, it is better to prove something stronger. In this case, it's better to prove that a(n) < 2(n!), or that a(n)<=2(n!)-1. This is true for n=1. Suppose it is true for n=k-1 for some k-1>=1. Then

```
a(k) = k(a(k-1))+1 
    <= k(2(k-1)!-1)+1 
     = 2(k!) +1-k 
    <= 2(k-1)!-1.
```

So, for any n>=1, a(n) < 2(n!). Since we have a lower bound and an upper bound of the form c*(n!), a(n) = Theta(n!).

Comment: I deleted my answer because I had messed up some mental arithmetic at the start, working on the wrong sequence. The right sequence has closed form `sum(factorial(n)/factorial(k) for k in range(n)) - factorial(n) + 1`.

Answer (score 3):

You have already noticed that your formula is very close to the factorial `n!`. Now you can express this finding in a more formal way: you can prove, for example, that

```
n! < a(n) < 2*n! (for big enough n)
```

If this is true, then all of `O`, `Θ` and `Ω` are `n!`.

I believe you can prove the inequality above, or some variant of it, using induction (haven't tried it though).

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Dividing a(n) by n!, the first terms are

```
a(1)/1! = 1/1! = 1
a(2)/2! = (2.1+1)/2! = 1 + 1/2!
a(3)/3! = (3.(2.1+1)+1)/3! = 1 + 1/2! + 1/3!
a(4)/4! = (4.(3.(2.1+1)+1)+1)/4!= 1 + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4!
...
```

This establishes the tight bracketing

```
n! <= a(n) < (e-1).n!
```

and `a(n)` is in `Θ(n!)`.

Comment: can you explain why are you dividing a(n) by n! did you just divide a(n) with the Omega(n!) ? Because your solution is the same as this from my Prof but i don´t know why i should do this

Comment: To understand how close the function is to n! Doing this allows to find an approximate closed formula.

Comment: Once you guess that the right form is c*n!, you can ask which c. If you can get constant  upper and lower bounds on a(n)/n!, you have established that a(n) is Theta(n), but you can hope to get the exact constant, which this answer provides.