# Solving a complex recurrence relation for the Traveling Salesman

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, computer-science, recurrence

I need to solve the exact time complexity for the brute force version of the Traveling Salesman using a recurrence relation.

I've worked out the recurrence relation to be as follows:
T(n)=T(n-1)*(n-1)+1

But I'm having trouble reducing that that to a closed form of the function, and thus get the exact time complexity. Not for lack of trying either. It's looking like it's coming out as a binomial sequence but my algebra is a bit rusty.

If anyone could help or point me on the right path I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: A good method for solving recurrence relations which aren't specified as a linear recurrence of fixed degree _with constant coefficients_ is to transform it to such - do you know how to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30015614/how-to-get-omegan/30016427#30016427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few hints :

- define R(n) = T(n)/(n-1)!
- solve the recurrence for R(n)
- express T(n) as a function of R(n)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I went down that path and while I'm not sure I did it right, after trial and error I am now getting T(n) = e(n!). (Approximately. That's e as in Euler's Number). That feels weird to me but is that right?

Comment: No, that looks good  -- just be careful that, at the level of precision you describe, (n-1)! is different from n!

Comment: That's what I meant, T(n)=e(n-1)! Thank's so much for your help! :D